# How to safely experiment with scripts that fork themselves

Tags: bash, fork, sandbox

I was experimenting with a bash script that would recursively fork and call itself. The terminating condition was subtle and I got it a wrong a few times, the result being a script that called itself ad infinitum. What's a safe way to sandbox a script like this while debugging it so that every time there's a mistake, I don't have to deal with stopping the infinite tower that fills up the process table?

Comment: I'd recommend against using recursion to create new processes, period. Use an iterative construct instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use ulimit

```
ulimit -u 20
```

Will limit the maximum number of processes runned by your user

Comment: Doesnt this limit the number of all processes instead of only the processes of the particular script?

Comment: @eckes Yes, but the OP is requesting for a sandbox to recover from fork bombs while debuging, so using a dedicated user or temporary limit the shell with ulimit does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply count the numbers of processes with your script name and terminate if the number gets too high.

[This blog post](http://samcaldwell.net/index.php/technical-articles/3-how-to-articles/68-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-linux-instances-of-a-given-process-using-a-bash-script) introduces a function to achieve this:

```
count_process(){
  return $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -c $1)
}
```

Explanation (taken from blog post):

- `ps -ef` will return a list of all running processes (in detail),
- and the process list will then be filtered first to exclude any instances of `grep`
- and second to count the processes specified with `$1`

For re-usability the author provides the function as little script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#   /usr/bin/processCount
#   Source: http://samcaldwell.net/index.php/technical-articles/3-how-to-articles/68-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-linux-instances-of-a-given-process-using-a-bash-script
# 
[ -z $1 ] && {
  echo " "
  echo "Missing expected input."
  echo " "
  echo "USAGE:"
  echo " "
  echo " $0 <executable file>"
  echo " "
  echo " NOTE: When executing this script use the path and filename of the"
  echo " program. Using only the process name can potentially return inaccurate"
  echo " results."
  echo " "
  exit 1
}

echo $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -v $0 | grep -c $1)

#script ends here.
```

Comment: @l0b0: http://askubuntu.com/questions/157075/why-does-ps-aux-grep-x-give-better-results-than-pgrep-x